# Delete array element in reversed array with delete_at not working

Tags: ruby, arrays, reverse

If I type `c.messages.reverse.delete_at(0)` nothing happens, where messages is the array. If I type `c.messages.delete_at(0)` it deletes the first element as it should. Why does this not work with reverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because [`reverse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse) returns a new array, of which you are deleting the last member. You *could* use [`reverse!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse), which mutates the original array.

If you want to remove the last element from an array, the best way would be to use [`pop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pop).

```
>> arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> arr.pop
=> "c"
>> arr
=> ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: I see, I will have to add the new array back to the object before saving to make it stick. Thanks!

Comment: The deleted array element could be at any position however, so I can't use pop. However it feels wrong to type:

messages = c.messages.reverse
messages.delete_at(params[:position].to_i)
c.messages = messages.reverse

This would invert the reverse and make it back to normal, what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: @jotun Can you use `messages.delete_at messaages.length - params[:position].to_i` ?

Comment: I just had to add in -1 like this: messages.length - 1 - params[:position].to_i to make it count properly.

Answer (score 2):

`delete_at` can handle a negative index, counting backward from the end of the array (-1 is the last element):

```
ar = [1,2,3,4,5]
ar.delete_at(-2)
p ar #=> [1, 2, 3, 5]
```